# PHP : unexpected 'echo' (T_ECHO) in /opt/lampp/htdocs/UI/user/index.php on line 156

Tags: php

I am doing a php variable deceleration  in url

i have piece of code

```
$message =  "Username or  password is not correct.";
header("Location:".echo get_site_url()."/UI/user/index.php?message={$message}");
```

Where get_site_url() is

```
$GLOBAL_URL_OF_THE_SITE= "http://webfaction";


function get_site_url(){

    global $GLOBAL_URL_OF_THE_SITE;

    return $GLOBAL_URL_OF_THE_SITE; 
}
```

Now I want to redirect the header on location

```
header("Location:http://webfaction/UI/user/index.php");
```

But why my code is giving this error

```
 Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'echo' (T_ECHO) in /opt/lampp/htdocs/UI/user/index.php on line 156
```

Comment: You don't need the echo in that line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `sprintf` to format your string properly

Try

```
header("Location:". sprintf("%s/UI/user/index.php?message=%s",get_site_url(),$message));
```

Answer (score 1):

Why are you adding `echo` in your `header` call like that?  `echo` is only for printing strings to the screen.  When using strings (or functions that return strings) otherwise, you don't need it.

```
header("Location:".get_site_url()."/UI/user/index.php?message={$message}");
```

Answer (score 0):

try it:

```
header("Location:".get_site_url()."/UI/user/index.php?message={$message}");
```

Answer (score 0):

It should read:

```
header("Location:".get_site_url()."/UI/user/index.php?message={$message}");
```

You dont need the echo there.. you're not trying to write to to the user, but keep it in the PHP code.

Answer (score 0):

```
header("Location:".echo get_site_url()."/UI/user/index.php?message={$message}");
```

becomes

```
header("Location:". get_site_url()."/UI/user/index.php?message={$message}");
```

Answer (score 0):

The `.` operator performs concatenation between strings, while `echo` renders the string to output.

Just get rid of `echo`.